# D3 negative value bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hi I need help with the negative values in my bar chart, it is currently not showing and only showing the positive values. It will output an error saying invalid negative value for rect.
How do i solve this? My code is

```
var dataset = [ (121651.391 / 1000), (226572.523 / 1000), (-7708.748564 / 1000), (165348.8828 / 1000), (87917.84251 / 1000), (129156.684 / 1000), (46133.22384 / 1000), (17775.32051 / 1000), (92209.22587 / 1000), (168072.8333 / 1000),(35361.62174 / 1000), (1195.90284 / 1000), (-2841.722459 / 1000), (-2841.722459 / 1000), (-1936.84912 / 1000), (8078.804727 / 1000), (-72495.06187 / 1000), (297950.5249 / 1000)];


//Width and height
var w = 500;
var h = 200;
var barPadding = 1;

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", w)
            .attr("height", h);

svg.selectAll("rect")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("rect")
   .attr("x", 0)
   .attr("y", 0)
   .attr("width", 20)
   .attr("height", 200)
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset.length);
})
  .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4;
})
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4);  
})
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
});
  svg.selectAll("text")
   .data(dataset)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
        return d;
   })
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length);
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - (d * 4);
   })
      .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length) + 5;  
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - (d * 4) + 15;              
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return i * (w / dataset.length) + (w / dataset.length - barPadding) / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - (d * 4) + 14;  
    });
```

any help greatly appreciated

Comment: If you have a negative value, change it to a positive value but shift it down so that the top of it is at 0. Elements can't have negative height.

Comment: um i dont quite understand you, do you mean for example -7708.748564 i just add 7708.747564 and just make the height bigger?

Answer (score 0):

First, height of the rect can not be a negative value.

What i can think is two ways listed here:

## 1. Do special handling to the start y position, this is simple and better way to achieve your purpose.

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/z9ucLqu2/38/) here.

```
.attr('y', function(d) {
    if(d.status === "System Error") {
        return height;
    }
    return y(d.duration) 
})
```

[image]

## 2.Maybe you can draw a positive rect, and use transform to rotate to do the trick.

Here is a fiddle to show you the transform

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/vRc6T/29/)

```
.attr("transform", function() {
    return d3.svg.transform()
        .translate(200, 100)
        //something like this
        .rotate(180)
        .translate(-d3.select(this).attr("width"), -d3.select(this).attr("height"))();
        
}
```